# Correct render of js object with nodejs express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have some structure that I want to render to my JADE page, so I decided to make JSON-like object to render some kind of data (variables, text,  js objects), this JSON object looks like :

```
var dataSet1 = {
    meta: {
        "name": "Some text",
        "minimum": mini_2,
        "maximum": maxi_2,
        "currentValue": last_data_2
    },
    data: {
        "values": dataTwo,
        "corridor": {
            "x1": xc,
            "x2": yc2,
            "yw": yw2
        }
    }
};
```

My render line:

```
res.render('index', {
    data_to_draw: JSON.stringify(dataSet1)
});
```

Then I`m using this rendered data on my JADE:

```
        displayGraphExampleOne("#graph",
                            !{data_to_draw.data.values},
                            !{data_to_draw.meta.currentValue},
                            !{data_to_draw.meta.minimum},
                            !{data_to_draw.meta.maximum},
                            !{data_to_draw.meta.name},
                            !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.x1},
                            !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.x2},
                            !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.yw2});
```

**Cannot read property 'values' of undefined** 
Im getting such type of error.
Im new with JS , so Im trying to decide what i`m doing wrong. If I will pass data not in js object - it works well, but i need such type of passing data.
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `JSON.stringify` the object, instead pass the object itself, otherwise you are trying to access the properties of a string, which obviously don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to format code like this:

```
var dataSet1= [

    {
        "meta": {
            "name": "Veocity variance",
            "minimum": mini_1,
            "maximum": maxi_1,
            "currentValue": last_data_1
        },

        "data": {
            "values": dataOne,
            "corridor": {
                "x1": xc,
                "x2": yc1,
                "yw": yw1
            }
        }
    }
];
```

And use such call:

```
displayGraphExampleOne("#graph",
        !{first_set}[0][0].data.values,
        !{first_set}[0][0].meta.currentValue,
        !{first_set}[0][0].meta.minimum,
        !{first_set}[0][0].meta.maximum,
        !{first_set}[0][0].meta.name,
        !{first_set}[0][0].data.corridor.x1,
        !{first_set}[0][0].data.corridor.x2,
        !{first_set}[0][0].data.corridor.yw);
```

But not forget to render:

```
res.render('index', {

    first_set:  JSON.stringify([dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3]),
    second_set: JSON.stringify([dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3]),
    third_set:  JSON.stringify([dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3])

                    });
```